# Multiport negation in iptables

Tags: linux, iptables

Consider I want to make a rule that if destination port of the incomming packet is any of the ports 80,120,130 for established or related states the system should drop it but other ports should be accepted.
I used something like the rule bellow. But that doesn't seem to work

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport ! --dports 80,120,130 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*doesn't seem to work*"?  Can you also cut-and-paste the output of `iptables -L -n -v` into your question, as the order of rules is important.

Comment: Can you please say is this rule correct for the logic I want? Does this rule drop packets to mentioned ports and doesn't for others?

Comment: No.  It permits those mentioned through; it merely fails to match, and has no effect on, others.

Comment: Already used such kind of negation with multiport and --dports/--sports. However, I'm not sure I understand the situation you need to address.

Comment: @MadHatter Why not? Doesn't it accept any ports other than those mentioned? I've wrote (!) before dport. Means if destination port number is not one of these, ACCEPT the packet. My question in comment was wrong. The question is does this rule accept any other ports than those mentioned, and it doesn't do anything for these 3 ports?

Comment: @tonioc This is the question: does this rule accept any other ports than those mentioned, and it doesn't do anything for these 3 ports?

Comment: This is the answer: that rule matches traffic to any TCP port other than those listed, and that traffic will be `ACCEPT`ed; like any rule, it has no effect at all on traffic that does not match it.

Comment: Yes thanks, but I wasn't sure if (!) causes the rule to work like what I expected. I mean I wanted to make sure it means like:
if (dport!=80 and dport!=120 and dport!=130) then ACCEPT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this rule works pretty much as you have described in your final comment above.  To be precise, in your metacode it matches, and therefore `ACCEPT`s, any packets that match:

```
protocol==tcp and (dport!=80 and dport!=120 and dport!=130) and (state==RELATED or state==ESTABLISHED)
```

Any other packets will not match this rule and therefore will not be disposed of by it.  Their fate will depend on other rules and/or policies.